# MySql: ORDER BY parent and child

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table like:

```
+------+---------+-
| id   | parent  |
+------+---------+
| 2043 |    NULL |
| 2044 |    2043 |
| 2045 |    2043 |
| 2049 |    2043 |
| 2047 |    NULL |
| 2048 |    2047 |
| 2049 |    2047 |
+------+---------+
```

which shows a simple, 2-level "parent-child"-corelation. How can I ORDER BY an SELECT-statement to get the order like in the list above, which means: 1st parent, childs of 1st parent, 2nd parent, childs of 2nd parent and so on (if I have that, I can add the ORDER BYs for the children... I hope). Is it possible withoug adding a sort-field?

Comment: I see id=2043 twice; please fix.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Including sorting children by id:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(parent, id), parent IS NOT NULL, id
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a63fc/4)

Explanation:

- `COALESCE(parent, id)`: First sort by (effectively grouping together) the parent's id.
- `parent IS NOT NULL`: Put the parent row on top of the group
- `id`: Finally sort all the children (same parent, and `parent` is not null)

Comment: That’s a problem on sqlfiddle’s end it seems. Try this one though http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63640/1

Answer (score 6):

If your table uses `0` instead of `null` to indicate an entry with no parent:

```
id   | parent
-------------
1233 | 0
1234 | 1233
1235 | 0
1236 | 1233
1237 | 1235
```

Use `greatest` instead of `coalesce` and check the value does not equal `0`:

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(parent, id), parent != 0, id
```

Comment: this didn't work, I had to use this: ORDER BY  COALESCE(IF(parent_id=0,NULL,parent_id), id), parent_id IS NOT NULL, id;

Answer (score 4):

This question still shows as one of the first search results. So I would like to share a my solution and hope it will help more people out. This will also work when you have a table with many levels of parent and child relations. Although it is quite a slow solution. The top level has `NULL` as parent.

```
+---------+---------+
| id      | parent  |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | NULL    |
| 2       | 1       |
| 3       | 1       |
| 4       | 2       |
+---------+---------+
```

In my approach I will use a procedure that will recursively call itself and keep prepending the path with the parent of the requested `id` until it reaches the `NULL` parent.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `PATH`(IN `input` INT, OUT `output` VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN

  DECLARE _id INT;
  DECLARE _parent INT;
  DECLARE _path VARCHAR(128);

  SET `max_sp_recursion_depth` = 50;

  SELECT `id`, `parent`
  INTO _id, _parent
  FROM `database`.`table`
  WHERE `table`.`id` = `input`;

  IF _parent IS NULL THEN
    SET _path = _id;
  ELSE
    CALL `PATH`(_parent, _path);
    SELECT CONCAT(_path, '-', _id) INTO _path;
  END IF;

  SELECT _path INTO `output`;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

To use the results in an `ORDER BY` clause you will need a `FUNCTION` too that wraps the results of the `PROCEDURE`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GETPATH`(`input` INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(128)
BEGIN

  CALL `PATH`(`input`, @path);
  RETURN @path;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now we can use the recursive path to sort the order of the table. On a table with 10000 rows it takes just over a second on my workstation.

```
SELECT `id`, `parent`, GETPATH(`id`) `path` FROM `database`.`table` ORDER BY `GETPATH`(`id`);
```

Example output:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+
| id      | parent  | path          |
+---------+---------+---------------+
| 1       | NULL    | 1             |
| 10      | 1       | 1-10          |
| 300     | 10      | 1-10-300      |
| 301     | 300     | 1-10-300-301  |
| 302     | 300     | 1-10-300-302  |
+---------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (1,39 sec)
```

Comment: after re-reading the initial question I see it was just asking about 2-level descendants where a single parent may have multiple descendants (siblings). This answer goes above and beyond and covers the case of N-level descendants which is what I needed

Comment: thankyou! it solve the problem for N-level of tree

Comment: It´s work nice, but I have one sugestion, the order in path is not ok because 1-10 is greater than 1-2 in numerical order, but not in text order, so I would change the line 'SELECT CONCAT(_path, '-', _id) INTO _path' adding a LPAD, like 'SELECT CONCAT(_path, '-', LPAD(_id,3,0)) INTO _path;.

Answer (score 3):

The solution above didn't work for me, my table used 0 instead of NULL.
I found this other solution: you create a column with the concatened parent id and child id in your query and you can sort the result by it .

```
SELECT CONCAT(IF(parent = 0,'',CONCAT('/',parent)),'/',id) AS gen_order
FROM table 
ORDER BY gen_order
```