# Can I sort children different than parent in CakePHP 3 threaded query?

Tags: cakephp, tree, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have a questions regarding threaded comments. Is it possible to order comments DESC and child comments ASC from this query (or table level) or should I make a after query modification?

Below you can find my query that orders all to DESC.

```

```
$comments = $this->Comments
            ->find('threaded', ['order' => ['Comments.created' => 'DESC']])
            ->contain(['Users'])
            ->matching(
                'BoardItems',
                function ($q) use ($boardItemId) {
                    return $q->where(
                        [
                            'BoardItems.id' => $boardItemId
                        ]
                    );
                }
            )
            ->all();
```

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### On SQL Level

You should be able to apply the solution suggested in **[MySql: ORDER BY parent and child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382380/mysql-order-by-parent-and-child)**, which

1. uses `COALESCE` to group/sort the parents first
2. groups the children by testing for a non-`NULL` parent ID
3. sorts the grouped children

In your case you'd sort by `created` instead of `id`, ie something like

```sql
ORDER BY 
    COALESCE(Comments.parent_id, Comments.created) DESC, 
    Comments.parent_id IS NOT NULL, 
    Comments.created ASC
```

To build this in a proper query builder-ish fashion, you'd have to use the `order()` and `orderDesc()` methods, so that you can use query expressions, something along the lines of

```
$query = $this->Comments
    ->find('threaded');

$comments = $query
    // ->contain(...)
    // ->matching(...)

    // COALESCE(Comments.parent_id, Comments.created) DESC
    ->orderDesc($query->func()->coalesce([
        'Comments.parent_id' => 'identifier',
        'Comments.created' => 'identifier'
    ]))

    // Comments.parent_id IS NOT NULL
    ->order($query->newExpr()->isNotNull('Comments.parent_id'))

    // Comments.created ASC
    ->order(['Comments.created' => 'ASC'])

    ->all();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**

### On PHP level

Sorting things afterwards would be an option too, for example using a recursive result formatter:

```
$sortChildren = function($row) use (&$sortChildren) {
    if (!empty($row['children'])) {
        $row['children'] =
            collection($row['children'])
                ->sortBy('created', SORT_ASC)
                ->map($sortChildren)
                ->toArray();
    }
    return $row;
};

$comments = $this->Comments
    ->find('threaded')
    // ->contain(...)
    // ->matching(...)
    ->order(['Comments.created' => 'DESC'])
    ->formatResults(function ($results) use ($sortChildren) {
        return $results->map($sortChildren);
    })
    ->all();
```

This would retrieve everything sort descending, and then sort all `children` arrays ascending by the `created` field. Similarily you could sort things before you output/use them in your views, depending on what exactly you're planning to do with the results.

If you want to keep things in the table, you could for example wrap this all up in a custom finder and/or retrieve the sort closure via a method on your table class.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Collections > Sorting](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#sorting)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections > Iterating](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#iterating)**

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, I'll be able to try on monday but from the looks of it, both will solve my issue. I was thinking of using something like the second one, using collections but the mysql solution seems better.

Comment: now finally tried mysql solution and worked perfectly, thanks again