# SELECT the table in hierarchy manner

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have a table like this:

```
----------------------
| id | Name | Parent |
......................
| 1  | Joe  |  ''    |
| 2  | Alice|  ''    |
| 3  | Manny|  ''    |
| 4  | kid1 |  1     |
| 5  | kid2 |  1     |
| 6  | kid3 |  3     |
```

and I want to display it in a hierarchy manner like this:

```
| id | Name | Parent |
......................
| 1  | Joe  |  ''    |
| 4  | kid1 |  1     |
| 5  | kid2 |  1     |
| 2  | Alice|  ''    |
| 3  | Manny|  ''    |
| 6  | kid3 |  3     |
```

Can I do it using only SQL commands?

---

Thank you so much guys.
I'm new to stackoverflow, yet I'm already amazed by how fast you have answered my question.

@amar duplantier, Thanks for the link it solved my problem!! I can't find that thread when I searched before.
I'm sorry I didn't provide enough information for my question.

here's the code I use based on amar's link:

```
select  *
from Table a
order by
        case 
        when Parent = '' 
        then id 
        else    (
                select  id 
                from    Table parent 
                where   parent.id = a.Parent
                ) 
        end
DESC
```

Comment: Any particular RDBMS? MySQL? SQL Server? Also, is the structure always only one level (ie no grand parents)?

Comment: is there any logic to your sort preference?

Comment: Check out this sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80369/6. Also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022158/how-do-i-order-by-parent-then-child

Comment: Search for recursive common table expression

Comment: Ah, sorry for the lacking of information.
I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `''` in the Parent column mean empty string then

```
SELECT   *
FROM     table1
ORDER BY Concat(Parent, ID)
       , ID
```

will return a resultset with the order the OP want (if there is only only level of hierarchy)

Comment: wow, never thought of this method before.
Yes this is working very good and short/not complex as well.
Thanks!

Comment: @Konthorn it uses the fact that the string order for number is not the same of the number order, it's probably the first time that I used it on purpose and not only to demostrate the difference between the two

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention a database in particular, so allow me to provide a solution using Oracle.

In Oracle you can perform START WITH and  CONNECTED BY:

`select id, Name, Parent 
  from your_table 
  start with parent is null
  connect by prior id = parent;`

Not all database have connected by, such as MySQL, but you can simulate it using functions: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Try Recurcive CTE:

```
WITH HierarchyTree (id, Name, Parent)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.id, e.Name, e.Parent
    FROM MyTable AS e
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.id, e.Name, e.Parent
    FROM MyTable AS e
    INNER JOIN HierarchyTree AS d
        ON e.Parent = d.id
)
SELECT id, Name, Parent
FROM HierarchyTree
GO
```