# Order by parent and children

Tags: mysql

I am looking at ordering my rows by their respective parent child relationships. One question has been answered that gets me half way and works but only for 2 levels. See [How do I order by parent then child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022158/how-do-i-order-by-parent-then-child)

As you can see the accepted answer mentions that it only works for 2 levels.

Here is my currently query.

My database looks like this.

| car_taxonomy_ID | car_taxonomy_parent | car_taxonomy_title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Title |
| 2 | 1 | Title |
| 3 | 2 | Title |
| 4 | 2 | Title |
| 5 | 1 | Title |

```
SELECT *
  FROM car_taxonomy AS feat
  ORDER BY CASE
              WHEN car_taxonomy_parent = 0 THEN car_taxonomy_title
              ELSE (
                SELECT car_taxonomy_title
                FROM   car_taxonomy AS parent
                WHERE  parent.car_taxonomy_ID = feat.car_taxonomy_parent
              )
            END,
            CASE
              WHEN car_taxonomy_parent = 0 THEN 1
            END DESC,
            car_taxonomy_title
```

But I have one more level to retrieve. What must be modified to get that third level

Comment: The link is for sql server you have tagged mysql what version of mysql are you on select version)

Comment: mysql version 5.7.26